# Custom Constraint(Validator) for different Types

Tags: java, validation, constraints

On the frontend side there's a form containing a selectbox filled with some options. The model contains a field which will be validated by my custom constraint:

```
private @Options(values=OptionKeys.SALUTATIONS) String salutation;
```

Which works great. Now I would like to have checkboxes or a multi value selectbox on the frontend side which uses the following snippet:

```
private @Options(values=OptionKeys.INTERESTS, optional=true) String[] interests;
```

Here's the constraint interface and the validator code:

```
@Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = OptionsValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Options {
    String message() default "{com.example.web.form.constraints.Options.message}";
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    boolean optional() default false;
    OptionKeys values();
}

public class OptionsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Options, String> {

    private List<String> values;
    private boolean optional;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Options params) {
        values = Arrays.asList(params.values().data);
        optional = params.optional();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (optional && StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
            return true;
        }

        return value != null && values.contains(value);
    }

}

public static enum OptionKeys {
    SALUTATIONS(new String[] {
            "m",
            "f"
    }),

    INTERESTS(new String[] {
            "dummy"
    });

    public final String[] data;
    OptionKeys(String[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to extend the validator somehow to also check `String[]` values or do I have to write another one (e.g. `@MultiOptions`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse the same annotation to validate different classes by providing more than one ConstraintValidators implementing the constraint. In the `@Constraint` annotation definition fill the `validatedBy` all applicable classes:

```
@Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {OptionsValidator.class, OptionsStringArrayValidator.class})
@Documented
public @interface Options {
   ...
}
```

and create corresponding implementations:

```
public class OptionsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Options, String> {...}
public class OptionsStringArrayValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Options, String[]> {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

One could use `Object` and check its type with `instanceof`:

```
public class OptionsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Options, Object> {
    private List<String> values;
    private boolean optional;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Options params) {
        values = Arrays.asList(params.values().data);
        optional = params.optional();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (optional && value == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (value instanceof String[]) {
            String[] valArray = (String[]) value;
            if (!optional && valArray.length == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            for (String val : valArray) {
                if (!values.contains(val)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            String val = (String) value;
            if (optional && val.trim() == "") {
                return true;
            }

            return val != null && values.contains(val);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Till there's currently no better solution (even there is a better one) this is the accepted answer.